# What packages do I need to include to use AutomationCore?

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I am setting up a C#/Selenium automation framework/test by following the article found [here](https://blog.testproject.io/2017/02/09/writing-functional-test/)

In the following code, "Test" is a custom test framework that was built in previous steps.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using Test;
namespace AutomatedTestCases
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Sanity : AutomationCore
    {
        [Test]
        public void ClickContactUs()
        {
            Browsers.getDriver.FindElement(By.Id("menu-item-1296")).Click();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is I can't find what package needs to be included in order to inherit from "AutomationCore" and the Google is failing me. Is this a typo or is there actually an AutomationCore class somewhere?

Comment: AutomationCore is a class that your Sanity class is inheriting from. You need to create that class and implement it first.

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot...I completely missed the last step of the previous steps. Thank you, please move your comment to an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: no worries sometimes we just need a 2nd pair of eyes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutomationCore is a class that your Sanity class is inheriting from. You need to create that class and implement it first.

Comment: Turns out I already created that class, but named it something other than AutomationCore. -1 to me for doing this tutorial over multiple days and forgetting what I did.